# Autoloading classes in php - is it a good practice?

Tags: php, autoload

There is some legacy php code I've got that has defined a function like this (and the

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    $filename=CLASSES. strtolower($class_name) . '_class.php';
    if (file_exists($filename))
    {
        require_once $filename;
    }
}
```

where CLASSES is the path where these particular (classname)_class.php files reside.

The above function is in a file that is included everywhere.

Is this an acceptable practice - any gotchas in using it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoload function loads a file if a class definition is not known. Therefore, as @fran-Verona and @Andy-Paton where afraid of, you do not need to worry you are autoloading all your classes.

You are loading the function in all your code, but you will load "verylittleusedclass.class.php" only when it is called (e.g. by `new VeryLittleUsedClass()` or trough a static call `VeryLittleUsedClass::theFunction()`).

I'd say it is good practice. You don't need to include all files without knowing if you still use them, the classes will be loaded if you need them.

You need to make sure you name your files correctly though.

Comment: Exactly, I was about to write this. `__autoload()` doesn't load all your classes, but only the one used in the current script. It's a very good practise *almost always* used by frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Nanne, Shikiryu for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a matter of preference.  I use a less generic autoload function to reduce the odds of including the wrong file.  It definitely cuts down on include maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use this autoloader https://gist.github.com/169617 (Also called as PEAR style autoloader)

It works with this convention

class name : Core_DB_Mysql
file path : Core/DB/Mysql

You can group your classes like ;

```
Core/Cache
     Core/Cache/APC
     Core/Cache/Memcache

Core/Models
     Core/Models/User
     Core/Models/Post
```

Ok with this convention you dont need to scan folders again and again

Answer (score 1):

THe good rule of thumb is to manually include all classes that you you know for sure will be used and leave the classes that may be used to autoloader.

For example, you may have a database library class, some type of settings class, internationalization class, registry class, interfaces definition classes, some type of custom exception class, templating engine class, and of cause the actual controller class that will be used.

So you should include all of them manually very close to the top of your 
index.php (or whatever file is first launched by browser) using 
include $file1.php
include $file2.php 
and so on....

This will give you the best performance and these classes are guaranteed to be cached by APC (if you use APC cache of cause)

Now inside your classes you may have some logic that conditionally uses one or the other class, depending of situation

For example

if(Request::isAjax()){
AjaxResponder::sendResponse();
} else {
return $page;
}

Now here it's OK to let autoloader to load AjaxResponder class since it may not even be needed.

So, if a class may not be needed, let autoloader handle it, otherwise include manually.

It's very simple rule really.

Also, it's very important to use the smart logic inside the autoloader function. Make sure 
you have as few conditional tests as possible and also never use any type of directory scan to find the class file.

If you use spl_autoload_register, then remember that to keep an eye of the order of registered autoload functions. The order if important.

A Good example of a smart autoloader class is here

http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal

Notice, it does not use any check to see if(file_exists()) or anything like that.
It just uses the 
require() and relies on the require function to raise error if file not found.

Never use include_once() or require_once inside your autoloader.
This does not make sense since autoloader will not be called in class is already included but require_once and include_once still have to perform extra check to see if file is already included.